# $(document).keydown not working

Tags: jquery

Edit::

Thanks Everyone for being helpful, but I tracked my problem as `<script src="jquery.js" />` instead of `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`. Please vote to close

Any idea why

```
$(function(){
   $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
         alert('Hello');
     }); 
})
```

is not working? I am using `Firefox 3.6.13` on Ubuntu 10.10. Well I copied it form [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/c08637641de52664?pli=1).

Comment: It works on my system (same FF version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `delegate()`:

```
$(window).delegate('*', 'keypress', function (evt){
        alert("erm");
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
  jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function (evt){
    alert('Hello');
  });
```

You may test if quick using firebug console (run it). You now get an alert box everytime you push a button on the document. I used Firefox 3.6.13 to verify this.