# Unable to bind keydown event to the entire document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some controls in my page (controls are kept inside iframe). i am binding keydown event to the controls as below,

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 74) { // j- key code.
                $("#accordion").focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

After the page load, if i press alt + J the control gets focused properly in chrome but not in **Firefox and IE**. The control gets focused, only if i click in the iframe area and then press the alt + J. If i remove the iframe the controls gets focused properly in all the browsers without the need to click on the iframe area. How can i make the controls to get focus if i press alt + J and without the need to click on the iframe area?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102214/document-keydown-not-working

Answer (score 2):

I think you could either use document.ready or window.onload

example please look below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 74) { // j- key code.
            $("#accordion").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Or

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 74) { // j- key code.
            $("#accordion").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it works in all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load()` event on iframe and get the contents with `.contents()` like this:

You can replace this line:

```
$("#accordion").focus();
```

with this code:

```
$('iframe').contents().load(function(){
    $(this).find("#accordion").focus();
});
```

If you are working with iframe then you have to wait for the iframe to be loaded then execute the `.focus()`